# Split Zip won't unsplit / recombine

Tags: zip

I have a 3.5 gb CSV file that I need to transfer in zipped, 10mb parts. However after going through the process of zipping and then splitting the zip, the recombining of the zip using `zip -s-`, `zip -s 0`, and `zip -FF` do not work.

```
$ du -h mycsv.csv
3.1G    mycsv.csv
```

First I create a zip file at maximum compression:

```
$ zip -9 maximum.zip mycsv.csv
adding: mycsv.csv (deflated 92%)
$ du -h maximum.zip
254M    maximum.zip
```

Then I use the `zip -s 10m` command to split the zip into many (26) 10 mb zip parts

```
zip -s 10m maximum.zip --out maxsplit.zip
copying: mycsv.csv
```

Then I use the `zip -s-` command to recombine the files into a single zip

```
$ zip -s- maxsplit.zip --out maxunsplit.zip
copying: mycsv.csv
```

However the file is a mere fraction of the expected size!

```
$ du -h maxunsplit.zip
21M maxunsplit.zip
```

Using an alternative command `zip -s 0` also fails

```
 $ zip -s 0 maxsplit.zip --out maxunsplit0.zip
 copying: mycsv.csv
 $ du -h maxunsplit0.zip
 21M    maxunsplit0.zip
```

And the other alternative command `zip -FF` also fails,

```
$ zip -FF maxsplit.zip --out maxunsplitFF.zip
Fix archive (-FF) - salvage what can
 Found end record (EOCDR) - says expect 26 splits
Scanning for entries...
  Found spanning marker - expected as this is split (multi-disk) archive...
 copying: mycsv.csv  (265820618 bytes)
    zip warning: entry truncated: mycsv.csv
    zip warning: expected compressed/stored size 265820618, actual 20971443
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0d 0d on disk 2 at 2711323

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0b 08 on disk 2 at 8427139

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 08 03 on disk 3 at 4921506

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0c 06 on disk 6 at 2338084

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 04 02 on disk 6 at 3998893

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0c 01 on disk 6 at 6941468

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0d 01 on disk 11 at 6509060

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 01 0b on disk 13 at 6769524

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 03 09 on disk 16 at 3164347

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0e 02 on disk 16 at 5817195

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 03 06 on disk 16 at 7044780

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0d 07 on disk 17 at 9182115

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 05 03 on disk 19 at 3063961

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 00 02 on disk 19 at 10170897

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0b 01 on disk 20 at 1420190

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 02 05 on disk 22 at 1010931

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 07 05 on disk 22 at 1918087

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 07 0b on disk 23 at 1507450

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0a 0a on disk 23 at 10456363

    zip warning: skipping this signature...
Central Directory found...
no local entry: mycsv.csv
EOCDR found (26 3676780)...
    zip warning: zip file empty
```

Finally some error messages, though I don't understand what they mean!?

Zip and Linux version:

```
$ zip --version
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.

$ uname -rosv
Linux 5.4.0-56-generic #62~18.04.1-Ubuntu GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I cannot help you with `zip`, which is an archiver and a compressor and a splitter and a concatenator and a verificator… According to the Unix Philosophy a tool should do one thing and do it well. `zip` doesn't follow, but there are tools that do. One can split *any* file with `split` and concatenate back with `cat`. Use `par2` to add redundancy if needed. This means you don't need to rely on `zip` to transfer `maxium.zip` (or any file) in parts. Making `zip` work would be a good thing, but in case you cannot, I'm letting you know there's a generic alternative way.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a (smaller) test. Is there a chance you ran out of disk space somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Thank you for your comments and advice. Perhaps the issue is with the zip tool and the total file size(3.5gb). There is a note in the related `man zipsplit` utility about a 2GB file limit, so perhaps `zip` also has issue. To move forward now, I've used `split -d -a 3 -b 100000000 mycsv.csv testsplit` and (individually zipped 26 files, transferred them, unzipped them) `cat testsplit{000..025} > togetheragain.csv` and confirmed with `sha1sum` that the input and output match.

Comment: This sounds like [bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=659535](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=659535) (or the linked [753314](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=753314)),
tried it with version 3.0-11+b1 (Debian buster), but had the same problem. Input file was only 133MB.